# Apache Isis apend HTML tag to VM (JAXB)

Tags: isis

I want to add some HTML tags to my View Module (JAXB), but I can't find any solution. e.g I want to display an `iframe` or add some `div` tags.

What I can add to my VM is `property` as bellow.

```
<cpt:property id="fieldName" cssClass="abc-class"/>
```

How can I create another tags similar to above, e.g `<cpt:iframe src="http://examle.com" />` into my `layout.xml`.

Another problem is `cssClass` on tag above doesn't work.

If I can add some HTML tag, I will be able to make my UI much more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems solve by using property using `org.apache.isis.applib.value.Markup`